# update jquery plugin options without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a plugin countdown with this code:

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    Location.reload();
    $("#biscuit").biscuit({
       Width : $("#width").val(),
       BgColor : $("#BgColor").val(),
    });
 });
```

I've created a form to update biscuit plugin options.The form is like below:

```
<p class="title">width</p>
<input id="width" name="width" value="150">
<p class="title">bgColor</p>
<input id="BgColor" name="width" value="#654321">  
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

I want to update biscuit plugin options after pressing submit button each time.These plugin options require me to refresh the page for the plugin to be updated.Please help me to find a way to update my plugin options after pressing submit button.
Thanks

Comment: how do you want to update biscuit actually, i mean what do you want to be updated.

Comment: I want to update width and BgColor options.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Location.reload();` and you have some errors with double quotes in your Jquery selectors.

I'm not 100% on $.biscuit() and whether the plugin updates that way but I would first try removing the `Location.reload();`, 
that is essentially reloading the page bringing it back to default values.

Comment: This plugin needs to be reloaded to accept new options parameters,because of that I wrote location.reload().Sorry for missing double quotes.I wrote it correctly in my code.If you want to update a plugin options with form not manually,how do you do it?

Comment: are you able to show the code where you instantiate `$.biscuit()`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){//now add e to your function
        e.preventDefault;//now prevent submit happen so it wont refresh
        Location.reload();
        $("#biscuit").biscuit({
           Width : $("#width").val(),//you forgot one " here
           BgColor : $("#BgColor").val(),//also you forgot one " here
        });
       });
```

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately it didn't work.If you have a form like this and such a plugin how dou you update it's options like width or BgColor?

Comment: Can you provide the plugin or at least a link to that plugin.So i can dig into more and help you better

Comment: ı actually think there should be update option for this plugin like .update or refresh but since i don't know what plugin you are using i can only guess

Comment: I've created this plugin by jquery create plugin solution.The plugin code lines near 1000 lines I think here I have limitation to share it.Can you show me how update plugin options with form?Think you created a plugin that needs to refresh page to be updated.And you want to change options value with form.Explain this situation.Thanks alot

Comment: @dewwweb hi, me again i think i find a solution for your case in another post. Check this one out maybe it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800095/how-to-correctly-implement-option-update-method-in-jquery-plugin